# Is there a way to use the Metadata API "purgeOnDelete" option within Salesforce DX / CLI?

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli

I'm trying to *erase* a lot of custom fields. I've managed to delete them, but they still exist in deleted fields.

The metadata API has a "purgeOnDelete" option to address this, but I don't see a way to do it with the CLI.

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/225 ...but you can build  `destructiveChanges.xml` with `purgeOnDelete` by hand or via a script and [run from there](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/276129/is-there-a-workflow-for-renaming-or-deleting-metadata-components-purely-with-an)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".

The easiest way to do this is probably via workbench with a destructiveChanges.xml. There, you'll have the option to select the "purgeOnDelete" option.

PSA: If you delete fields in DX, those fields will have to be **erased manually**. Not a huge deal for a few fields but quite a bummer for 600+. Totally not speaking from experience :D